# Network Proxy in intranet

Tags: java, http-proxy

I'm beginner to network concept in a Java application, So pardon me, if I'm wrong.

I'm accessing both internet as well intranet. We have different IP segments in our network(intranet). I'm little bit confused with Proxy concepts. All I'm talking is about HTTP communication only. When I try to access internet remote servers(www.google.com), I should configure proxy in my application and it is working fine. But for intranet, for some servers can be accessed through proxy, some servers not responding with proxy. So can you help me, where should I use proxy where I shouldn't.?

Comment: I can assure you that nobody here knows how your network is configured. I'd suggest talking to your IT department and looking at how your web browser is configured to access the various servers. Good luck.

Comment: OK, I thought it is generic. OK, I'll check. Thanks.

Comment: I'll check and provide the answer in such scenario.